# how to Create a monthly recurring payment cycle with php and mysql event scheduler?

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a partnership system that will award `x amount` to a partner based on the package they sign up for `every 30 days` from the day of sign up

This is the structure of my table

[image]

So basically what I want to do is to Check for every partner
If interval between `date_time` and `last_paid = 30days` and `package = a` then add `x amount` to balance.

**NOTE: last_paid is set to ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();**

I read about `MySQL` event schedulers but I do not seem to understand it, please point me in the right direction as to how to attain this. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to store (what is apparently) easily derivable data?

Comment: How will you suggest I approch this?

Comment: Store the date that the user joined. And calculate the difference as and when you need it.

Comment: Please can you give a code sample to demonstrate?

Comment: If you research how to find the difference between 2 dates using mySQL (which is easy to google already) then you should find the solution becomes much clearer. Try it. If you get stuck again, come back and ask again.

Comment: @ADyson I don't have a challenge calculating the defference between two dates. My challenge is assigning the `amount` to the partner  `when the time defferences = 30days`.

Comment: Well if the difference of the two dates (in days) is a multiple of 30 then you'll know that today is pay day for that person. Or you can extend the concept in the answer below - that calculates how many payouts they should have had by now. If you have another table which records whenever you actually make a payment, then if the number of actual payments for a partner is less than the number of payments due by now, then, again, you'll know it's time to pay them.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(partner_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,signup_date DATE
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'2020-01-01'),
(2,'2020-03-15'),
(3,'2020-05-14'),
(4,'2020-07-13'),
(5,'2020-09-21');

SELECT partner_id
     , FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),signup_date)/30) awards 
  FROM my_table;
+------------+--------+
| partner_id | awards |
+------------+--------+
|          1 |      9 |
|          2 |      7 |
|          3 |      5 |
|          4 |      3 |
|          5 |      0 |
+------------+--------+
```